# Time evolution of a spin-coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, eigenvalue, coherent-states

What i'm struggling with is this question:

Consider a spin S in an external magnetic field along the quantization axis so that the $|S_{z}>$ states are eigenstates with equally spaced eigenvalues E = $-h$$S_{z}$.  For this Hamiltonian describe the time evolution of a spin-coherent state and relate it to the classical angular momentum dynamics.

Attempt at a solution:

So i've previously derived that when the time evolution operator $U(t)$ acts on a coherent state i.e. $U(t)|\alpha(0)>$ = $e^{\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}}|\alpha(0)>$
this becomes  $U(t)|\alpha(0)>$ = $e^{\frac{-i\omega t}{2}}|\alpha(0)e^{-i\omega t}>$ = $e^{\frac{-i\omega t}{2}}|\alpha(t)>$, which i'm not sure whether will help or not.

I'm guessing here that $\vec{B} = B\vec{z}$, and that possibly the hamiltonian is $H=− μ⃗ · B⃗ = −g q S⃗ · B⃗ = -gqS_{z}B_{z}$  but I don't know where to go from there.

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I will refer to your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327983/quantum-mechanical-spin-coherent-states) for some basics but will use a different notation.
Let $z=\tan(\theta/2)e^{i\phi}$.  The evolution of the spin coherent state
\begin{align}
\vert z\rangle&:=\frac{1}{(1+\vert z\vert^2)^J}
\sum_{M=-J}^J z^{J-M}{{2J}\choose{J+M}}^{1/2}\vert JM\rangle\, ,
\end{align}
should be something like
\begin{align}
e^{-i\alpha S_zt}\vert z\rangle&= 
\frac{1}{(1+\vert z\vert^2)^J}
\sum_{M=-J}^J z^{J-M}{{2J}\choose{J+M}}^{1/2}e^{-i\alpha M t}\vert JM\rangle\, ,\\
&=e^{-i\alpha J t}\frac{1}{(1+\vert z\vert^2)^J}
\sum_{M=-J}^J z^{J-M}{{2J}\choose{J+M}}^{1/2}e^{-i\alpha (M-J) t}\vert JM\rangle\, ,\\
&=e^{-i\alpha J t}\vert e^{i\alpha t}z\rangle\, .
\end{align}
Please check carefully and make adjustments to your notation but this should give you enough of a hint.

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you explain what alpha is in your equations?

Comment: Your Hamiltonian is something like $H=-gqB_z S_z$ so I guess this makes my $\alpha$ your $-gqB_z$

Comment: Ah great I see. Is there also supposed to be a $1/\hbar$ in the leftmost exponential as well?

Comment: Probably yes.  You should double check but I think if you take the eigenvalues of $S_z$ to be $\hbar M$ then the $\hbar$s cancel.